# Why do people just downvote without giving reason?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Why do people just downvote without giving ANY REASON or COMMENTING?
Recently I've read a question, saw downvotes and got angry.
Someone Comment and says, "Maybe they downvote because you include the whole code but added a part of code after that." something like this.

---

PROBLEM[1] : GOTO WAS UNEXPECTED AT THIS TIME

But, sometimes, they got problem on SOMEWHERE ELSE:

e.g. [Batch script: goto was unexpected. using find xyz file.log && goto pass || goto fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360941/batch-script-goto-was-unexpected-using-find-xyz-file-log-goto-pass-goto?rq=1)

PROBLEM[1] is not in this page - it's on the another.

---

Why downvote without reason? If there are many downvotes & nobody explain,
**HOW CAN SOMEBODY IMPROVE??**

Comment: This question reads more like a rant than a discussion. Step away from the computer, calm down, cool off, then try again; I guarantee the reception will be better.

Comment: I really want to downvote this because it's an unclear rant to my eyes, but I don't want to reinforce your prejudice.

Comment: Here is a related discussion on this topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213985/why-do-people-downvote-questions/213987#213987

Comment: I **did** down vote because you've failed to do even the most basic research before asking this question. Did you try [searching Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote+comment)? Did you investigate any of the suggested links that appeared above your question as you typed? Did you read what is available at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: asdfasdfsadfasdf

Comment: It is a hard life at meta. It reputation can be <0, I will be at -32. MAYBE KICKED.

Answer (score 17):

I can't speak for others, so what I'll say here is how I see my commentless downvotes. The downvote tooltip says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*.

Most often when I downvote without commenting, it's just that. Completely unclear or not useful at all. And so much so that anyone should really be able to see that from looking at the question. If the problems are more subtle I generally do leave a comment, if a similar comment hasn't already been made. If it has been, I'll upvote that comment.

This assumes a couple of things though: I assume that you as the user have familiarized yourself with the site before asking your question. You have done the minimal you should do and have read what the site is about, read about what is on-topic and off-topic, and you've researched what you're asking and demonstrate that you have.

If your question subsequently is off-topic, unresearched, or one of countless duplicates, you might not get my comment. I could downvote you and will vote to close if necessary.

In general I love helping you (the user) out, and I'll do my best to make your stay as pleasant as can be, but I don't usually feel like explaining those issues again that I feel you should have at a minimum familiarized yourself with. So you might end up with a commentless downvote from me for those reasons. (Though in practice I often still will explain or ask for a thing or two before doing so)